# How to rm directory which name has quotation and question marks on macOS

Tags: shell, rm

I have two directory which name are very strange as below:

```
"?????+ "BizComponent               
"?+ "BizComponent
```

and now I try to remove them but failed. when I type `rm -r '` then type `tab` it give me:

```
"^J^I^I^I^I+ "BizComponent/BizComponent/        
"^J+ "BizComponent/
```

And then, when I type `rm -r "^J^I^I^I^I+ "BizComponent/BizComponent/` it gives me *No such file or directory*

Comment: Why not just remove the completed filenames?

Comment: `rm -r "^J^I^I^I^I+ "BizComponent/BizComponent/` will consider the double-quote as shell quoting, and the command will be executed without the quote. If the quote is part of the name, you need to preserve the quote either by escaping it or by additional quoting. It would be easiest to just use glob: `rm -r *BizComponent*`.

Comment: @Amadan I have another normal direction which name contains *BizComponent* . And I can rename them then rm -r \*BizComponent\* but I want to know if there exist more directly solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your filename contains a special character, but this is not necessarily the character you see. Example (taken from [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#coreutils)):

```
$ touch zzz yyy $'zzz\nyyy'
$ ls
yyy  zzz  zzz?yyy
```

As you see, a filename with a new line was created, but `ls` printed it as a `?`. So how do we remove this?

**method 1:**
An option available to `ls` is `--quoting-style=shell-escape`, this allows you to see how to type the filename for removal (works on files and directories):

```
$ ls --quoting-style=shell-escape
yyy   zzz  'zzz'$'\n''yyy'
$ rm 'zzz'$'\n''yyy'
$ ls
yyy   zzz
```

**method 2:** The second method is to use the inode number using `find` (works on files and directories):

```
$ touch zzz yyy $'zzz\nyyy'
$ ls -li
total 2
3886009 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Jul 23 12:56 yyy
3886008 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Jul 23 12:56 zzz
 662083 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Jul 23 12:56 zzz?yyy
$ find . -inum 662083 -delete      
$ ls -li
total 1
3886009 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Jul 23 12:56 yyy
3886008 -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Jul 23 12:56 zzz
```

Comment: the first method is very cool, but it seemed my mac shell dont support it. It tell me `ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]` and the second method worked.

Comment: You can install GNU ls. `brew install coreutils` then stick this into your `.bash_profile`: `alias ls='/usr/local/bin/gls --color=auto'` (this will make the first method work too). Bonus: Mac's `ls` is limited to 16 colours, GNU `ls` is way prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some special characters in your directory names.  You could use a loop with a glob:

```
for dir in *BizComponent; do
  rm -r -- "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the shell expansion you need to escape the special characters `? + " ^` and `space`. So to reference your files, you need to remove/reference them likes this:

`rm -rf \"\?\?\?\?\?+\ \"BizComponent/`

`rm -rf  \"\?\+\ \"BizComponent`

`rm -rf \"\^J\^I\^I\^I\^I+\ \"BizComponent/BizComponent/`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `rm -rf "?????+ BizComponent" | echo $?`